# Popping queue of 2d arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, queue

I have a queue of 2d arrays.

I would like to look at the elements of the topmost entry of the array. Array list is a queue of type int**.

```
int** target = arraylist.pop();
```

is correct. However,

```
for (int k = 0; k < cities; k++)
    for (int m = 0; m < cities; m++)
        if (targ[k][m] != 0) <----- segfault here
```

This is my top function:

```
template <class T>

T Queue<T>::top()
{
    return data[front];
}
```

and my queue is declared as

```
Queue<int**> arraylist;
```

I know int** does not necessarily mean int [x][y], but I am curious to see why this is the case and what I can do to set the topmost entry of the queue to a 2d array variable.

Comment: Are you sure you are not going out of bounds or your array was initialized properly in first place?

Comment: I checked to see whether k and m were out of bounds. They were not. I initialized both the 2d arrays I put into my queue and my temporary targ array using new.

Comment: I doubt anyone would be able to answer your question with certainty given only those 4 lines of code. Please construct a [**Minimal**, **Complete**, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that instead.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

though not in the code you paste, i guess either the implement of your `Queue::push()` or the place you call your `Queue::push()` cause this.

Did you copy the data in you implement of `Queue::push()` ?

Or you copy a pointer and the data be pointed may have been release? Or more complicate, you push a same pointer several times and one of them have been pop by you and release?